# FIrebase Firestore onCreate Cloud Function Event Params Undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have tried following Firebase's documentation and other SO posts to access a parameter value for a cloud function I've successfully deployed.

Unfortunately I've still been receiving a

> Type Error: cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I've logged event.params and it is outputting as undefined, so I understand the issue, but am unsure how, syntactically, I'm supposed to derive the param value.

Below is my js code for reference:

```
exports.observeCreate = functions.firestore.document('/pathOne/{id}/pathTwo/{anotherId}').onCreate(event => {
  console.log(event.params);

  //event prints out data but params undefined...
  const data = event.data()

  var id = event.params.id;

  return admin.firestore().collection('path').doc(id).get().then(doc => {
    const data = doc.data();
    var fcmToken = data.fcmToken;

    var message = {
      notification: {
        title: "x",
        body: "x"
      },
      token: fcmToken
    };

    admin.messaging().send(message)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        return;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        return;
      });

      return;
  })
})
```

Comment: [here's a somewhat close case working example](https://hightechtele.com/articles/firestore-trigger-email). ...Like Doug said the `1.0` release introduced breaking changes and most of what you find online examples uses the `pre-1.0` library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using the pre-1.0 API for the firebase-functions module, but the acutal version of it you have installed is 1.0 or later.  The API changed in 1.0.  [Read about the changes here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).

Firestore (and other types of) triggers now take a second parameter of type [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext).  This has a property called `params` that contains the data that used to be in event.params.

```
exports.observeCreate = functions.firestore.document('/pathOne/{id}/pathTwo/{anotherId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  console.log(context.params);
  console.log(context.params.id);
});
```

Please also [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) for the most up-to-date information about Firestore triggers.